# Having issue with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am having an issue with the setInterval() function in javascript where it will print to my page once and it will not continue to do so. I was wondering if maybe this is a browser issue or something i did wrong.

```
function printTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "<br/>");
}

setInterval("printTime()", 1000);
```

Comment: try setInterval(printTime, 1000); Although yours should also work since printTime seems to be global?

Comment: What browser you are using? I just tested your code in Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: I was using Firefox and I tried IE.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the poor practice of using `"functionName()"` instead of just `functionName`, the code will never work if the interval is beyond the page loading.

`document.write` will wipe the page after load

Here is a better solution:

```
<div id="time"></div>
<script>
function pad(str) { return ("0"+str).slice(-2)}
function printTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML+=pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds) + "<br/>";
}

setInterval(printTime, 1000);
</script>
```